# Root directory '/' locked after using chmod

Tags: permissions, root, chmod

I accidentally used

```
sudo chmod 3 /
```

which gives a execute and write permission to the root directory, while deleting the read permission. How can I recover from this, I cannot even use `sudo` now.

Comment: Regarding "unable to sudo", if all else fails and you have the access and knowledge to tinker with the boot loader, add `init=/bin/bash` to the `kernel` line. That makes the machine boot directly into a bash with root priviledges, enabling you to fix blunders like these, and others. Corollary: If Mallory gets access to the boot process, your system security is shot. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can't use `sudo`, try the following command instead (you'll get root privileges with [pkexec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pkexec.1.html)):

```
pkexec chmod 755 /
```

Tested ok in a VM:

```
u@u-VirtualBox:/$ sudo chmod 3 /
[sudo] password for u: 
u@u-VirtualBox:/$ ll
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
u@u-VirtualBox:/$ sudo chmod 755 /
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
u@u-VirtualBox:/$ pkexec chmod 755 /
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/chmod' as the super user
Authenticating as: u,,, (u)
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
u@u-VirtualBox:/$ ll
total 104
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root  4096 oct.  12 20:22 ./
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root  4096 oct.  12 20:22 ../
[...]
u@u-VirtualBox:/$
```

Comment: I guess he can't run any other executable, since they are all under `/`.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: I tested OP command in a VM, `pkexec` restored the initial permissions on `/`. See my logs.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Now that it's verified to work, I think it's far better than mine. :D

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto OP was lucky that it was `chmod 3`, and not `chmod 2` or `chmod 4`.

Answer (score 2):

First, try other suggestions while still logged in, because mine requires a reboot. If you see that no other attempt works, you should reboot and start a live DVD/USB session.

Mount the root partition and edit the `/etc/fstab` as root. You will need to run a command similar to this:

```
gksu gedit /media/ubuntu/sda1/etc/fstab
```

Please **adjust the path** to the correct mount point you used.

In the file, locate the line belonging to the root partition, it should look similar to the following:

```
UUID=[...] /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Try to enforce "universal" permissions by adding the proper parameter:

```
UUID=[...] /               ext4    umask=000,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Reboot and try to log in again. You should be able to fix the permissions with:

```
sudo chmod 755 /
```

## Warning

After the fix, remember to **revert** the changes made to `/etc/fstab`, otherwise anyone will be able to access and modify every system file.

Comment: `umask` masks the values (think negation), so a umask of 777 *disables* all permissions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just fix the `/` permissions from the Live DVD? After all, if you use a Linux live, you'll probably be able to manipulate the mounted filesystem without trouble.

Comment: since when does umask work on ext4?

Comment: @muru, you are right. I corrected the mistake. @John WH Smith, probably that's possible as well. I wasn't sure how to do it so I wrote my answer this way. @Joshua, there is nothing in `man umask` which excludes ext4. Is this limitation documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I also did this almost exactly. The way I solved it was I first restarted my device, went to advanced options, and launched recovery mode. This gives you a root shell to work with. In the root shell, you can use chmod 755 / (the default) and it will go back to normal. It works because root can read, write, or execute anything regardless of permissions.